# Segfault on pointer to array access

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pixel

I am writing a small wrapper around freeimage for image loading and pixel grabbing among other things. I have a `PImage` class which deals with all loading and displaying, and inside this it holds a `PixelColorBuffer` class. I use the `PixelColorBuffer` for a convenient way to grab the `unsigned char`s from the `texturebuffer` and convert them into another class called `color` (which I excluded since it works fine). I also want to be able to set pixels using this `PixelColorBuffer` class, which is why it has `colortobuffer` and `buffertocolor`. I instantiate `PixelColorBuffer` with a pointer to where the `unsigned char array` is (note: that holds the rgba values for the picture). However, this seems to work, yet when I call `get(10, 10)` on an image that is loaded and displaying I get the following:

```
(GNU Debugger)
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7bc66d9 in cprocessing::PixelColorBuffer::buffertocolor (this=<optimized out>, n=<error reading variable: Unhandled dwarf expression opcode 0x0>) at pixelcolorbuffer.cpp:17
17      c.rgba[0]=(*b)[(n*4)+0];
```

The `PImage` and `PixelColorBuffer` classes are compiled into a `.so` and linked properly. I am assuming I am doing something wrong with setting the pointer, this is the first time I've dealt with pointers to pointers... yet I can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is all relevant code.

```
///MAIN_PROGRAM.CPP
PImage t;
t.loadImage("image.png"); //loads image (works)
image(t, mouseX, mouseY); //draws image (works)
color c = t.get(10, 10); //SEGFAULT



///PIMAGE.HPP
class PImage {
public:
    GLubyte * texturebuffer; //holds rgba bytes here
    PixelColorBuffer * pixels;

    PImage();
    color get(int x, int y);
};


///PIMAGE.CPP
PImage::PImage() {
    this->pixels = new PixelColorBuffer((unsigned char *) texturebuffer);
}

void PImage::loadImage(const char * src) {
    //...snip...freeimage loading / opengl code ...
    char * tempbuffer = (char*)FreeImage_GetBits(imagen);
    texturebuffer = new GLubyte[4*w*h];

    //FreeImage loads in BGR format, so we swap some bytes
    for(int j= 0; j<w*h; j++){
        texturebuffer[j*4+0]= tempbuffer[j*4+2];
        texturebuffer[j*4+1]= tempbuffer[j*4+1];
        texturebuffer[j*4+2]= tempbuffer[j*4+0];
        texturebuffer[j*4+3]= tempbuffer[j*4+3];
    }
    //...snip...freeimage loading / opengl code ...
}

color PImage::get(int x, int y) {
    return pixels->buffertocolor((y*w)+x);
}



///PIXELCOLORBUFFER.HPP
class PixelColorBuffer {    
public:
    unsigned char ** b;

    PixelColorBuffer(unsigned char * b);

    /**Converts a pixel from the buffer into the color
    * @param n pixel ((y*width)+x)
    * @return color*/
    color buffertocolor(int n);

    /**Converts a pixel from the buffer into the color
    * @param n pixel ((y*width)+x)
    * @param c color to put into buffer*/
    void colortobuffer(int n, const color& c);
};



///PIXELCOLORBUFFER.CPP
PixelColorBuffer::PixelColorBuffer(unsigned char * b) {
    this->b = &b;
}

color PixelColorBuffer::buffertocolor(int n) {
    color c(0, styles[styles.size()-1].maxA);
    c.rgba[0]=(*b)[(n*4)+0];
    c.rgba[1]=(*b)[(n*4)+1];
    c.rgba[2]=(*b)[(n*4)+2];
    c.rgba[3]=(*b)[(n*4)+3];
    return c;
}

void PixelColorBuffer::colortobuffer(int n, const color& c) {
    (*b)[(n*4)+0] = c.rgba[0];
    (*b)[(n*4)+1] = c.rgba[1];
    (*b)[(n*4)+2] = c.rgba[2];
    (*b)[(n*4)+3] = c.rgba[3];
}
```

Comment: I guess first I'll ask, is your image larger than 10 by 10?

Comment: This code is not complete nor correct, and I'll bet it's not minimal.

Comment: Yes. Something a few hundred by a few hundred. That would be funny if that was the case.

Comment: @Beta Well I tried to strip out everything that isn't relevant. I don't know how I could reduce it more without making it ambiguous. I can access texturebuffer fine it is only the PixelColorBuffer class I have issue with/ if you have suggestions on cleanup I'd be glad to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this->b = &b;` -- you are initializing b to be a pointer to a stack value.

Change the argument to a `unsigned char*&` to fix this immediate problem with your code.  To fix long term problems, stop messing around with pointers.  (This will cause an error somewhere else, but it will fix the undefined behavior here!)

`(unsigned char *)` don't use C style casts in C++ code.  Use the C++ style casts, they are both less dangerous and say what you intend to do.

`unsigned char ** b` why do you have a pointer to a pointer to a buffer of unsigned characters anyhow?  And why are you hanging around with a buffer without any idea of how long it is?

`texturebuffer = new GLubyte[4*w*h];` in C++, it is a good idea to use some kind of ownership class to wrap allocations, so you know what pointer "owns" the data, and is responsible for cleaning it up.

`this->pixels = new PixelColorBuffer((unsigned char *) texturebuffer);` is there any reason why your `PixelColorBuffer` needs to be dynamically allocated?  Why not have an actual `PixelColorBuffer` in your class/struct, instead of the overhead and mess of putting it on the free store?

First, teach a `PixelColorBuffer` how to be empty.  Second, don't dynamically allocate it.  Third, if you write a non-trivial constructor that allocates memory, you must write a destructor, a copy constructor and `operator=`.  You can choose to disable the copy constructor and the `operator=` instead of writing them.  (Google "rule of three C++")

Then whenever you update your `texturebuffer`, tell the `PixelColorBuffer` to point at a new source of pixels.  This gets rid of the need to have a `char**` in `PixelColorBuffer`.

Ideally, store your `texturebuffer` in a managed buffer, like a `std::vector` instead of using `new` -- why manage memory when someone else can do it?  This does away with a need to write a destructor (but you still need to disable `=` and copy construction).

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I never knew *& was a thing, so I still have a lot to learn. I'll look into c++ cats, I assume your referring to the dynamic/static sort I've seen? On your questions: PixelColorBuffer didn't need to be dynamic. There are destructors and operators on PixelColorBuffer- just left them out. I think I was overthinking with the double pointer- because a single one could work as well. I was under the impression that using a vector in this case would be slower than what I attempted? Again thank you, I feel I have learnt multiple things here.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably not the whole story, but two obvious problems:

```
PImage::PImage() {
    this->pixels = new PixelColorBuffer((unsigned char *) texturebuffer);
}
```

This line is invalid because `texturebuffer` is uninitialized there. (Reading from uninitialized variables causes undefined behavior).

```
PixelColorBuffer::PixelColorBuffer(unsigned char * b) {
    this->b = &b;
}
```

This line points `this->b` at `b`, which is a local variable (a parameter) in `PixelColorBuffer::PixelColorBuffer`. After the constructor returns, `this->b` is an invalid pointer.

Comment: I see, I was under the impression that it would work due to texturebuffer being declared. I think I now understand the scope of functions (in regards to pointers) as well. Thanks for the help, learnt a few things!